# How can I fix the Error Invalid Sec-WebSocket-Accept header in Node js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, header, cryptojs

I am trying to create client websocket in node js. The websocket server is running in the browser (firefox). code and error message are below. It isn't working in Nodejs  while it's working in the browser. What's the reason for this? How can I solve?

**Code (Node JS):**

```
    const WebSocket = require('ws');
    const { randomBytes } = require('crypto');
        const headers = {
          Accept: '*/*',
          'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
          'Accept-Language': 'q=0.8,en-US',
          'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
          Connection: 'keep-alive, Upgrade',
          cookie: 'key=UE2BQmTF;',
          Pragma: 'no-cache',
          'Sec-WebSocket-Extensions': 'permessage-deflate',
          'sec-websocket-key': randomBytes(16).toString('base64'),
          'Sec-WebSocket-Version': '13',
          Upgrade: 'websocket',
          'User-Agent':
            'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:72.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/72.0',
        };
 ws = new WebSocket(wurl, { headers });
  ws.binaryType = 'arraybuffer';
  ws.on('open', () => {
    console.log('connected', Date());
 });

  ws.on('close', () => {
    console.log('disconnected', Date());
  });
```

**Error:**

```
Error: Invalid Sec-WebSocket-Accept header
2020-01-25T14:51:57.930773+00:00 app[web.1]: at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/ws/lib/websocket.js:603:7)
2020-01-25T14:51:57.930775+00:00 app[web.1]: at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:223:5)
2020-01-25T14:51:57.930778+00:00 app[web.1]: at TLSSocket.socketOnData (_http_client.js:490:11)
2020-01-25T14:51:57.930780+00:00 app[web.1]: at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:223:5)
2020-01-25T14:51:57.930782+00:00 app[web.1]: at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:309:12)
2020-01-25T14:51:57.930785+00:00 app[web.1]: at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:290:11)
2020-01-25T14:51:57.930787+00:00 app[web.1]: at TLSSocket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:224:10)
2020-01-25T14:51:57.930789+00:00 app[web.1]: at TLSWrap.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:181:23)
2020-01-25T14:51:57.930791+00:00 app[web.1]: Emitted 'error' event on WebSocket instance at:
2020-01-25T14:51:57.930793+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:313:26)
2020-01-25T14:51:57.930795+00:00 app[web.1]: at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:223:5)
2020-01-25T14:51:57.930797+00:00 app[web.1]: at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:92:8)
2020-01-25T14:51:57.930799+00:00 app[web.1]: at emitErrorAndCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:60:3)
2020-01-25T14:51:57.930801+00:00 app[web.1]: at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:81:21)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

'sec-websocket-key' is automatically generated by ws
[sec-websocket-key](https://github.com/websockets/ws/blob/9535702e50525621313941f0e1a972fdca403045/lib/websocket.js#L503)